# Display the value from database to dynamically created textfield in the table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

I going to display the value from the database to the dynamically created textfields to each table cell using JQuery. (Note that the fetch values Im going to display are not all same.) The 'lvl' (e.g. lvl1 or lvl2) are the values from database, not an id or class of textfields.

Here's what it looks like..

```
      | itm1 | itm2 | itm3 | itm4 | itm5
------|------|------|------|------|-----
skill1| lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl1 | lvl4 | lvl0
------|------|------|------|------|-----
skill2| lvl1 | lvl0 | lvl4 | lvl2 | lvl1
------|------|------|------|------|-----
skill3| lvl4 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl0 | lvl1
```

My JQuery,

```
$('tbody tr td').click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest('td');
  var skill = row.find('.skillID').val();
  var item = row.parent().children().index(row);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/get_level",
    data: {'Skill_ID':skill,'Item_ID':item},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       alert("Level "+data);
     }
  });
});
```

The above code was successful in alert and click func, but I need to display the data in textfield by clicking the "td" or when the page was loaded, the value would display automatically.

view,

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
       <td><?php echo $item->ItemID ?></td>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach($skills as $skill): ?>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <?php for($i=0; $i<count($items); $i ++){ ?>
       <td><input type="text" value="" />
       <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="<?php echo $skill->Skill_ID" ?> />
       </td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - you do not even post an example of the data retrieved or any HTML. Please search for "parse json jquery" if it is JSON

Comment: If I got you right, lvl2 may be the text field in the table cell, Then update the value on the success of ajax call  like  $(".lvl2").val(data);

Comment: "yes, lvl2/lv3 and so on are the texfields in the table"

Comment: but the lvl's are the values im going to fetch.. not actually the id or class of a textfield.

Comment: i don't see any class name like `.skillID` in your html

Comment: i had just updated my question

Comment: what you trying to get from this line `var item = row.parent().children().index(row);` ?

Comment: the column number actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('tbody tr td').click(function() {
  var col = $(this).closest('td');
  var skill = col.find('.skillID').val();
  var index = col.index();
  var item = $('table thead tr').find('td').eq(index).text();

  console.log('Skill_ID - ' + skill + ';\nItem_ID - ' + item);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/get_level",
    data: {
      'Skill_ID': skill,
      'Item_ID': item
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      col.find("input[type=text]").val("Level " + data);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td>Item2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Skill 1</td>
      <td title="lvl2">
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl2" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td title="lvl1">
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl1" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td title="lvl3">
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Skill 2</td>
      <td title="lvl3">
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl3" />
      </td>
      <td title="lvl2">
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl2" />
      </td>
      <td title="lvl1">
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" class="skillID" value="lvl1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this works. Since I don't have your public url for making ajax. The snippet wont work.

If you need to attain this with out clicking, then you have to change your script to doc ready method like:

```js
$(function() {
  $('tbody tr td').each(function() {
    var col = $(this);
    var skill = col.find('.skillID').val();
    var index = col.index();
    var item = $('table thead tr').find('td').eq(index).text();

    console.log('Skill_ID - ' + skill + ';\nItem_ID - ' + item);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/get_level",
      data: {
        'Skill_ID': skill,
        'Item_ID': item
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        col.find("input[type=text]").val("Level " + data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: wow, the idea of getting the values in the thead was great since i dunno how to get it at first, im only using the column number as a cheat to get the value of the column. thanks for that.

Comment: yey, its working, but how am i supposed to do if i want the values to display automatically, not by clicking every single td's?